# Spring-boot dependendency

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependency-management, spring-boot-starter

I have a maven project which has `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.7.10` as a parent with `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency.

I upgraded `spring-boot-starter-web` to use `<version>3.0.5</version>`.

But in the mvn dependency:tree I still get `spring-webmvc` old version which is 5.3.20.

When I tried to open pom of `spring-boot-starter-web` it clearly shows compile dependency of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.7</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone help me to understand why upgrading `spring-boot-starter-web` version did not upgrade spring-webmvc version? I have explicitly added to resolve this for now:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>            
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.7</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I am not sure if it is the correct way of upgrading such hierarchical dependencies.

> Note: that my end goal was to upgrade spring-webmvc to  6.0.7 from 5.3.20

Comment: Could you please paste the dependency:tree result?

Comment: I cannot recreate your problem using the info in your question. My `spring-webmvc` JAR was upgraded from `5.3` to `6.0` - without any need to explicitly include it as a dependency. I only changed the parent POM.

Comment: Without seeing your list of dependencies this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: If you want to upgrade spring-webmvc to 6.X (meaning spring framework to version 6) you have to migrate to Spring Boot 3.0.X.... and don't mix different versions of spring boot (spring-boot-starter-web 3.0.5 and spring boot parent 2.7.10)

Answer (score 0):

You should manage versions only in the parent pom.
Try upgrading spring-boot-starter-parent to 3.0.5 and let the version of spring-boot-starter-web be implicit (remove the version tag).
If you want more precise dependency management and not let your parent's versions leak, use the dependencyManagement tag

Answer (score 0):

To get the dependencies path to `spring-webmvc`, run:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework:spring-webmvc
```

This should show you the offending dependency chain.
Output example (showing for `spring-core` because that's what the available project I happen to have):

[image]

First line in the tree is your project. Second is its direct dependencies. Third and onward are transitive dependencies.

Once you know which is it, you can either:

- Upgrade it - assuming an upgrade is available and that it doesn't have any undesired side-effects; or
- Remove it - if, say, it's an unused dependency.